# Mongoose & getting average of ratings in a collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, average

I have a NodeJS based application using Mongoose. I am wanting to create a response where there values are an average of ratings provided by people who have responded to a questionnaire, for each question asked.

My Schema looks as follows:

```
const questionnaireResultSchema = new Schema({      
   user: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   questionnaire: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Questionnaire' },
   rating: [{
       id: Number,
       question: String,
       value: Number
   }]
},{
    timestamps: true
}).index({user: 1, questionnaire: 1}, {unique: true});
```

I have looked at the Mongoose [aggregator operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/), but I am not sure how I would apply it to my case. Pseudo code would look as follows:

- Find all questionnaire results for questionnaire of id xyz
- Provide a result where the ratings for each questionnaire result has be averaged

For example the response would look as follows:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   question: 'How strongly do you feel about candidate A?',
   value: 12 // averaged value
 },{
   id: 2,
   question: 'How strongly do you think we should change the sky color to green?',
   value: 31 // averaged value
 },{
   id: 3,
   question: 'How strongly do you think your answers count?',
   value: 20 // averaged value
 }]
```

I have tried:

```
QuestionnaireResultSchema.aggregate([{ 
    $match: {
        questionnaire: questionnaire
    }},
        {$project: {
            scores: { $avg: '$scores'}
        }}
    ]);
```

This just provides the JSON:

```
[{
    "_id": "57bbd4b495407f6145b3ba9f",
    "scores": null
}]
```

A sample document in a collection would like:

```
 {
    user: ObjectId("57bca30536e376c653f439bb")
    questionnaire: ObjectId("37bca0feedb0bc470353ab")
    scores:     [{
        id: 1,
        question: 'How strongly do you feel about candidate A?',
        value: 3
      },{
        id: 2,
        question: 'How strongly do you think we should change the sky color to green?',
        value: 4 // averaged value
      },{
        id: 3,
        question: 'How strongly do you think your answers count?',
        value: 5 // averaged value
      }]
   }
```

While I could calculate the averages myself, if Mongoose provides the functionality, I would rather leverage that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the question as asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your aggregation pipeline:

```
[
    {
        $match: {
            questionnaire: ObjectId("37bca0feedb0bc470353ab")
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$rating"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id:{
                "rating_id": "$rating.id",
                "question": "$rating.question",
            },
            avg_rating: {$avg:"rating.value"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "id": "$_id.rating_id",
            "question": "$_id.question",
            "avg_rating": "$avg_rating"
        }
    }
]
```

Although your sample doc has "scores" instead of "rating" in which case you'd use:

```
[
    {
        $match: {
            questionnaire: ObjectId("237bca0feedb0bc470353aba")
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$scores"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id:{
                "rating_id": "$scores.id",
                "question": "$scores.question",
            },
            avg_rating: {$avg:"scores.value"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "id": "$_id.rating_id",
            "question": "$_id.question",
            "avg_rating": "$avg_rating"
        }
    }
]
```

Also, some of the ObjectId's that you are using are not valid.  I'm assuming those are just stubbed.

Comment: This works for me. The ObjectIds I provided weren't real ones, I just provided fake values for the example. BTW is there any reason you use the _id to transfer the other values from the group to the project?

Comment: Yes, every time you $group you need to specify an _id for the group.  It's mandatory.  It's the unique group by key that you want to use.  Then the $project is just used to bring the values that make up the key back out to the root level of the document.